Сортировка слиянием Си
Пожалуйста помогите реализовать функцию
int merge ( const int *a , int ak , const int *b , int bk , int * res );

Где а - первая последовательность. Уже отсортирована по возрастанию
аk - кол-во элементов в а
b - вторая последовательность. Уже отсортирована по возрастанию
bk - кол-во элементов b
res - последовательность которая должна получится после слияния.
мой неработающий код:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void merge ( const int *a , int ak , const int *b , int bk , int * res )
 {
         if (ak > bk) {
    
    for (int j = 0; j < ak; j++){
        if (a[j] > b[j]) res[j] = a[j];
        else res[j] = b[j];

    }
  
}  else {
      for (int j = 0; j < bk; j++){
        if (a[j] > b[j]) res[j] = a[j];
        else res[j] = b[j];
      }
   }
}
int main()
{
 FILE* inside = fopen("imp.txt", "rb");
 FILE* outside = fopen("ump.txt","wb");
 unsigned int n;
 fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, inside);  //first 4 bytes

 int *pn = malloc(n * sizeof(n));

 unsigned int m;
 fread(&m, sizeof(m), 1, inside);
 int *pm = malloc(m * sizeof(m));

 for(int w = 0; w < n; w++){
    fread(&pn[w], sizeof(n), 1, inside);
 }
 for(int w = 0; w < n; w++){
    fread(&pm[w], sizeof(m), 1, inside);
 }

 int *result = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
 merge(pn, n, pm, m, result);
 fwrite(&result,sizeof(result), 1, outside);
 fclose(inside);
 fclose(outside);
 return 0;
 }
}


А где ваша попытка слияния? Здесь только недоделанный код подготовки данных (сколько памяти под result выделено?)

Слияние делают в константной памяти. Массивы не нужны. И я согласен с MBo, вы поместили в вопрос только рыбу для ввода/вывода. Нужна ваша попытка решения, "доказательство работы".

обновил, не заметил

результат слияния должно помещать все элементы обоих массивов. А в вашем исполнении остаются только выборочные элементы. Нужно подправить алгоритм добавлением отдельных индексов для трёх массивов.

Размер result n+m. В процедуре merge нужно сделать общий цикл, и про индексы всё верно сказали

merge (...) { int j = 0, ia = 0, ib = 0; while (ia < ak && ib < bk) { if (a[ia] <= b[ib]) res[j++] = a[ia++]; else res[j++] = b[ib++]; } while (ia < ak) res[j++] = a[ia++]; while (ib < ib) res[j++] = b[ib++];} (первый while крутится пока в обеих массивах (a[] и b[]) еще есть не просмотренные элементы,  из последних 2-х while-ов будет работать только один. Почему так, понятно?)

Логика закрывателей вопроса мне совершенно не понятна (мы же тут помогаем людям, а не воспитываем их?)

И да, (время редактирования пердыдущего комментария истекло) тело первого while можно записать и короче  и более отражающим суть дела -- { res[j++] = (a[ia] <= b[ib]) ? a[ia++] : b[ib++]; }

@avp, я голосовал за закрытие, когда в вопросе не было кода функции merge. Позже вопрос был исправлен, я этого не заметил. За повторное открытие не проголосовал, не знал про него. Вся история. Не вся: проголосовал за открытие только что. Не верю, что из этого что-то выйдет.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, по моим наблюдениям (крайне не систематическим) повторное открытие ни к чему не приводит. А вот первоначальное закрытие обычно просто сразу убивает тему. Так что, ответов тут скорее всего уже не будет, да и поезд ушел, и дорога ложка к обеду. Поэтому я и не приветствую закрытие вопросов вообще

@avp, в ваших словах что-то есть. Надо подумать. Спасибо.
